# Display Data in New Tab in Same Browser[Working Code]

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a Google Script that Displays List of Data from Google Drive and this is what it looks like.

[image]

This code is working so perfect you just need `index.html` and `code.gs` and here is the code for both of them. (So for those who are using google app script in your site this will help.)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .my_text
     {
        font-family:    Tahoma;
        font-size:      13px;
        font-weight:    normal;
     }
</style>

<base target="_top">

<script>
function displayMessage() 
{
        var searchTerm;
        searchTerm = document.getElementById('idSrchTerm').value;
        console.log('searchTerm: ' + searchTerm );
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(handleResults).processForm(searchTerm.replace("'","\'")); 
}            
        function handleResults(results){      
        var length=results.length;
        var table = document.getElementById("output");
        var count = document.getElementById("count");

             for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
             {
                var item=results[i];
                item=item.split("|~|");
                count.innerHTML = "Total Records Found : " + length;
                table.innerHTML  +="</br><a href='"+item[1]+"' target='_blank'>"+item[0]+"</a></br>  <B>Owner: </B>" +item[3]+ "</br><B>Last modified: </B>"+item[2]+ "</br> <B>File Size: </B>"+item[4]+"</br>";           
             }

}

function clearBox(elementID)
{
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>

<style>
table, th, td 
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
       <p class = "my_text">Search File : <input type="text" id="idSrchTerm" name="search" class = "my_text">
       <input type="button" value="Search Drive" name="submitButton" class = "my_text" onClick="clearBox(); displayMessage();"/>
</div> 

<div id = "count" class = "my_text"></div>
<div id ="output" class = "my_text">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) { // main function
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index.html');
  return template.evaluate().setTitle('Search Drive').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


function SearchFiles(searchTerm) {
  var searchFor ="fullText contains '" + searchTerm + "'"; 
  var names = [];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor); 
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    var lm = file.getLastUpdated();
    var OType = file.getOwner().getName();
    var fsize = file.getSize()
    var name = file.getName()+"|~|"+file.getUrl()+"|~|"+lm+"|~|"+OType+"|~|"+fsize; 
    names.push(name); 
    Logger.log(file.getUrl());
  }
  return names; 

function processForm(searchTerm) {
  var resultToReturn;
  Logger.log('processForm was called! ' + searchTerm);
  resultToReturn  = SearchFiles(searchTerm); 
  Logger.log('resultToReturn: ' + resultToReturn);
  return resultToReturn; 
}
}
```

My only target here is how can I display the result in `New Window`? I mean I will type any string in textbox and click the button then thats it! the output will display in a new window like for example `output.html`

TYSM for future help.

Comment: and here is the other questions that I`ve posted that is related to this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428526/prevent-blank-page-and-display-data-in-table?noredirect=1#comment75868717_44428526 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407931/display-list-of-files-inside-table/44413025#44413025

Comment: Do you want a new ***browser*** tab to open?  Or a new browser window?  As opposed to a new tab inside of the HTML.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply its weekend here so its hard open a PC here in my place, Anyway a New Tab will do. I mean a new tab next to my current tab (where Im running this code) in the same `Browser (G Chrome)`

Comment: I will edit my question header for a better understanding

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: Sir please take a look at my question in `code.gs` looks like what you advise does not fit here or if you have any way to accomplish please let me know i can try it now. TYSM for the effort.

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think it's possible to move from one .html page to another .html like navigating a regular website. Although, it's possible to display the contents of somePage.html file into your mainPage.html file (the one specified in doGet(e) ) using scriptlets, <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('NAME_OF_OTHER_HTML_FILE').getContent(); ?>.

Comment: even in new tab in same browser is not possible? whats the best way to solve this?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script/16697525#16697525) answers my question. :)